# What is the safest way to convert scraped URLs to real URLs?

Tags: java, relative-url

I scrape a website and find these links on a page:

```
index.html
bla.html
/index.html
A.com/test.html
http://wwww.B.com/bla.html
```

If I know the current page is www.A.com/some/path, how can I convert these links into "real Urls" effectively. So, in each case, the urls should translate to:

```
index.html => http://www.A.com/some/path/index.html
bla.html => http://www.A.com/some/path/bla.html
/index.html => http://www.A.com/index.html
A.com/test.html => http://www.A.com/test.html
http://wwww.B.com/bla.html => http://wwww.B.com/bla.html
```

What is the most effective way to convert these on-page links to their fully qualified url names?

Comment: Do you have any attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `java.net.URL` class:

```
URL BASE_PATH = new URL("http://www.A.com/some/path");
String RELATIVE_PATH = "index.html";
URL absolute = new URL(BASE_PATH, RELATIVE_PATH);
```

It will resolve the relative URL against the base path. If the relative URL is actually an absolute URL, it will return it instead.

Answer (score 1):

@Brigham's Answer is correct but incomplete.

The problem is that the page where you scraped the URLs from could include a `<base>` element in the `<head>`.  This base URL may be *significantly* different to the URL that you fetched the page from.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://www.example.com/">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

In the `...` sections, any relative URLs will be resolved relative to the `base` URL rather than the original page URL.

---

What this means that if you want to resolve "scraped" URLs correctly in all cases, you also need to look for any `<base>` elements as you are "scraping".